# Is it possible to remove css blur effect to specific area of full div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div with background images which has blur effect.

### html

```
 <div class="background-image"></div>
 <div class="content">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis aliquam erat in ante malesuada, facilisis semper nulla semper. Phasellus sapien neque, faucibus in malesuada quis, lacinia et libero. Sed sed turpis tellus. Etiam ac aliquam tortor, eleifend rhoncus metus. Ut turpis massa, sollicitudin sit amet molestie a, posuere sit amet nisl. Mauris tincidunt cursus posuere. Nam commodo libero quis lacus sodales, nec feugiat ante posuere. Donec pulvinar auctor commodo. Donec egestas diam ut mi adipiscing, quis lacinia mauris condimentum. Quisque quis odio venenatis, venenatis nisi a, vehicula ipsum. Etiam at nisl eu felis vulputate porta.</p>
     <p>Fusce ut placerat eros. Aliquam consequat in augue sed convallis. Donec orci urna, tincidunt vel dui at, elementum semper dolor. Donec tincidunt risus sed magna dictum, quis luctus metus volutpat. Donec accumsan et nunc vulputate accumsan. Vestibulum tempor, erat in mattis fringilla, elit urna ornare nunc, vel pretium elit sem quis orci. Vivamus condimentum dictum tempor. Nam at est ante. Sed lobortis et lorem in sagittis. In suscipit in est et vehicula.</p>
 </div>
```

### css

```
 .background-image {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    display: block;
    background-image: url('a.JPG');
    width: 1200px;
    height: 800px;

   -webkit-filter: blur(10px);
   -moz-filter: blur(10px);
   -o-filter: blur(10px);
   -ms-filter: blur(10px);
    filter: blur(10px);
 }
```

When I mouse hover on `backgroung-image` div, I want to remove blur effect where mouse pointer is located. Is it possible from jquery. This is the example that I want to achieve. [example](https://www.canva.com)

Comment: I think I saw something similar to this a couple of days back but was using SVG. If you are fine with using SVG, I will try and see if I can dig that one.

Comment: You will find answers **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049177/how-to-reveal-part-of-blurred-image-where-mouse-is-hovered)** with both SVG and jquery

Comment: I don't know about SVG. I will search and learn. It would be great if you can try it. But isn't it be possible from jquery.\

Comment: My solution is using JavaScript. You can create an element "magnifier" has same backgound image, but make it crop a part of image. Maintain your current background.

When mouse move on background image, element "magnifier" also move follow mouse pointer, and modify background-position to show image at corresponding position on background image.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle with a jQuery solution.It blurs hovered part of image .Hope it helps:

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WP2C/3/)

**jQuery**

```
$('.pic').mousemove(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var upX=event.clientX;
    var upY=event.clientY;
    $('#blurr').css({'display':'block','top':''+(upY-15)+'px','left':''+(upX-15)+'px'});
});
```

**CSS**

```
.pic{
    display:inline-block;
}
/*below CSS for the blurring div*/
#blurr{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px white;
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px white;
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px 10px white;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

---

## Update 28/Feb/2014

### [Fiddle : Reveal part of transparent-overlayed image](http://jsfiddle.net/Zword/stzmL/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="blurPic"></div>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IGKVr8r.png" alt="follow picture" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
}
.blurPic{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 160px white inset; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 160px white inset; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 160px white inset; 
    -ms-box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 160px white inset; 
    opacity:0.9;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0.9); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

**jQuery**

```
/**Give equal width and height as <img> to .blurPic**/
var hgt = $('.blurPic').width($('#container img').width());
$('.blurPic').height($('#container img').height());
/*****************************************************/

/*******Get shadow values*****/
var result = $('.blurPic').css('boxShadow').match(/(-?\d+px)|(rgb\(.+\))/g)
var color = result[0],
    y = result[1],
    x = result[2],
    blur = result[3];
/******************************/

/**Change box-shadow on mousemove over image**/
var blurStartW = hgt.width()/2;
var blurStartH = hgt.height()/2;
$('.blurPic').mousemove(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var scrollLeftPos = $(window).scrollLeft(),
    scrollTopPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
    offsetLft = hgt.offset().left,
    offsetTp = hgt.offset().top;
    var upX=event.clientX;
    var upY=event.clientY;
    $(this).css({boxShadow : ''+(-offsetLft+upX-blurStartW+scrollLeftPos)+'px '+(-offsetTp+upY-blurStartH+scrollTopPos)+'px 20px 100px white inset'});
});
/*********************************************/

/***reset box-shadow on mouseout***/
$('.blurPic').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).css({boxShadow : '0px 0px 0px 160px white inset'});
});
/**********************************/
```

---

## Update 01/Mar/2014

### [Fiddle : Reveal part of Blurred image][3]

***The above fiddle uses [Vague.js][4]*** because **CSS3** blurring may not work in all browsers

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/IGKVr8r.png" alt="follow picture" />
    <div class="revealPic"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
    margin-left:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.revealPic{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-image:url('http://i.imgur.com/IGKVr8r.png');
    background-color:white;
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    /*making div circular*/
    border-radius:50%;
    -moz-border-radius:50%;
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    -ms-border-radius:50%;
    -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var hgt = $('#container'),
    bgt = $('#container .revealPic');

var bgtHalfW = bgt.width()/2,
    bgtHalfH = bgt.height()/2;

/**Change position of .revealPic and background-image within it on mousemove over container**/
hgt.mousemove(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    bgt.show();
    var scrollLeftPos = $(window).scrollLeft(),
    scrollTopPos = $(window).scrollTop(),
    offsetLft = hgt.offset().left,
    offsetTp = hgt.offset().top;
    var upX=event.clientX;
    var upY=event.clientY;
    bgt.css({backgroundPosition : ''+(offsetLft-upX+bgtHalfW-scrollLeftPos)+'px '+(offsetTp-upY+bgtHalfH-scrollTopPos)+'px',top:''+(-offsetTp+upY-bgtHalfH+scrollTopPos)+'px',left:''+(-offsetLft+upX-bgtHalfW+scrollLeftPos)+'px'});
});
/*********************************************/

/*Hide .revealPic div on mouseout*/
hgt.mouseout(function(){
    bgt.hide();
});
/*********************************/

/*Using vague.js to make blurred image*/
var vague = $("#container img").Vague({intensity:10});
vague.blur();
/**************************************/
```