# How to blur all of an image except for where the cursor is

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There's a cool effect [here](https://www.canva.com/) at the login screen that I would like to duplicate.

There is an answer on how to reveal part of a blurred image [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049177/how-to-reveal-part-of-blurred-image-where-mouse-is-hovered), but it isn't as complicated as the target example.

Is this possible to do with only html, css, and js (jquery and other plugins are fine)?

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved.* Please include your expected results, your attempted solutions, and why they didn't work. Please see the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922) for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using Jquery.I have created a codepen with a jQuery solution. 
Check this out: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MalemScha/pen/NamYYM) 
 
**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
  background: url(https://static.canva.com/static/images/bg_tiles.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
(function() {
  window.navigator.userAgent.match(/Macintosh/);
  $(n);
  function n() {
    $("form").each(function() {
      0 === $(window).height() / 2
        ? window.setTimeout(function() {
            n();
          }, 100)
        : $(this).css("margin-top", -$(this).outerHeight() / 2);
    });
  }
  function r(a, b) {
    this.j = (this.i = "PUBLIC" !== a) ? a : "*";
    this.o = b;
  }
  r.prototype.init = function(a) {
    window.addEventListener(
      "message",
      function(b) {
        b = b.data;
        b.isCanvaApi && (a[b.type] || $.noop)(b);
      },
      !1
    );
    this.sendMessage({ type: "Init", authenticated: this.i });
  };
  r.prototype.sendMessage = function(a) {
    a.isCanvaApi = !0;
    this.o.postMessage(a, this.j);
  };
  function u() {
    var a = { embedDomain: "PUBLIC" };
    function b(c) {
      0 === $(c.target).closest("#loginForm, #signupForm").length &&
        f.sendMessage({ type: "LoginSignup", action: "hide" });
    }
    function k(c) {
      c = c.emailAddress;
      h();
      c && ($("#loginUsername").val(c), $("#emailSignup #email").val(c));
      d();
    }
    function d() {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        f.sendMessage({ type: "LoginSignup", action: "show" });
      }, 300);
    }
    function g() {
      var c = $("body")
        .css("background-image")
        .replace("url", "")
        .replace("(", "")
        .replace(")", "")
        .replace(/["']/g, "");
      f.sendMessage({
        type: "LoginSignup",
        action: "pageTransition",
        u: c
      });
    }
    function h() {
      $("html").addClass("embedded");
      $(".embedded canvas").css("display", "none");
      if (/login\?redirect/gi.test(window.location.href)) {
        var c = window.location.href
            .replace("login?", "signup?")
            .replace("redirect", "signupRedirect"),
          c = c + "%3Fonboarding%26layouts";
        $(function() {
          if (1 === $("#signupLinkWrapper a").length)
            $("#signupLinkWrapper a").attr("href", c),
              $("#signupLinkWrapper a").on("mousedown", g);
          else {
            var a = $('\x3ca href\x3d"' + c + '"\x3eSignup now\x3c/a\x3e');
            a.on("mousedown", g);
            $("#loginForm .message")
              .html("Don\x26#8217;t have an account?")
              .append(a);
          }
        });
      } else if (/signup\?signupRedirect/gi.test(window.location.href)) {
        var a = window.location.href
          .replace("signup?", "login?")
          .replace("signupRedirect", "redirect");
        $(function() {
          if (1 === $("#loginLinkWrapper a").length)
            $("#loginLinkWrapper a").attr("href", a),
              $("#loginLinkWrapper a").on("mousedown", g);
          else {
            var c = $(
                '\x3cp style\x3d"margin-top:2em;"\x3eAlready have an account?\x3c/p\x3e'
              ),
              d = $('\x3ca href\x3d"' + a + '"\x3eLogin\x3c/a\x3e');
            c.append(d);
            d.on("mousedown", g);
            $("#signupForm").append(c);
          }
        });
      }
      var d = document.createElement("style");
      d.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
      var e = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
      d.styleSheet
        ? (d.styleSheet.cssText =
            "\n.embedded header { display: none !important; } .embedded footer { display: none !important; } .embedded body \x3e canvas { display: none !important; } ")
        : d.appendChild(
            document.createTextNode(
              "\n.embedded header { display: none !important; } .embedded footer { display: none !important; } .embedded body \x3e canvas { display: none !important; } "
            )
          );
      e.appendChild(d);
      $("header").hide();
      $("footer").hide();
    }
    if (window != window.top) {
      var f = new r(a.embedDomain, window.parent);
      f.init({
        blur: function() {},
        focus: function() {},
        registerOrShowLogin: k
      });
      f.sendMessage({ type: "LoginSignup" });
      window.addEventListener("click", b, !1);
    }
  }
  window !== window.top && u();
  (function() {
    function a() {
      $("body").mousemove(function(a) {
        m = a.clientX;
        q = a.clientY;
        t = Date.now();
        p || k();
      });
      $(window)
        .on("blur mouseout", function() {
          q = m = null;
        })
        .on("resize", function() {
          d && d.parentNode && d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
          b();
        });
      b();
    }
    function b() {
      var a = null == g ? !0 : !1;
      d = document.createElement("canvas");
      d.width = $(window).width();
      d.height = $(window).height();
      $("body").append(d);
      g = document.createElement("canvas");
      g.width = $(window).width();
      g.height = $(window).height();
      if (d.getContext && d.getContext("2d")) {
        h = d.getContext("2d");
        f = g.getContext("2d");
        f.lineCap = "round";
        f.shadowColor = "#000000";
        f.shadowBlur = 30;
        c = new Image();
        var e = $("body").css("background-image");
        e &&
          ($(c).one("load", function() {
            a && k();
          }),
          (e = e
            .replace(/url\((.*)\)/, "$1")
            .replace(/["']/gi, "")
            .replace(/\.jpg/, "_color.jpg")),
          $(c).attr("src", e),
          (e = $(
            '\x3cdiv style\x3d"position:absolute;height:0;width:0;overflow:hidden;"\x3e\x3c/div\x3e'
          )),
          $("body").append(e),
          e.append(c));
      }
    }
    function k() {
      var a,
        b = Date.now();
      p = b > t + 500 ? !1 : !0;
      m && p && e.splice(0, 0, { time: b, x: m, y: q });
      for (a = 0; a < e.length; )
        1e3 < b - e[a].time ? e.splice(a, e.length) : a++;
      0 < e.length && window.l(k);
      f.clearRect(0, 0, g.width, g.height);
      for (a = 1; a < e.length; a++) {
        var v = Math.sqrt(
          Math.pow(e[a].x - e[a - 1].x, 2) + Math.pow(e[a].y - e[a - 1].y, 2)
        );
        f.strokeStyle =
          "rgba(0,0,0," + Math.max(1 - (b - e[a].time) / 1e3, 0) + ")";
        f.lineWidth = 25 + 75 * Math.max(1 - v / 50, 0);
        f.beginPath();
        f.moveTo(e[a - 1].x, e[a - 1].y);
        f.lineTo(e[a].x, e[a].y);
        f.stroke();
      }
      a = d.width;
      b = d.width / c.naturalWidth * c.naturalHeight;
      b < d.height &&
        ((b = d.height), (a = d.height / c.naturalHeight * c.naturalWidth));
      h.drawImage(c, 0, 0, a, b);
      h.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
      h.drawImage(g, 0, 0);
      h.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
    }
    var d,
      g,
      h,
      f,
      c,
      m = null,
      q = null,
      e = [],
      t = 0,
      p = !0;
    "createTouch" in document || $(a);
    window.l = (function() {
      return (
        window.requestAnimationFrame ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
        function(a) {
          window.setTimeout(a, 1e3 / 60);
        }
      );
    })();
  })();
  $(function() {
    $("menu .dropdown").on("mouseover", function() {
      if (0 >= $(this).parents("#movedMenus").length) {
        var a = $(this),
          b = Number(a.data("timer"));
        null != b && clearTimeout(b);
        b = setTimeout(function() {
          a
            .parent()
            .find("li.hover")
            .not(a)
            .removeClass("hover")
            .addClass("hoverOff");
          a.removeClass("hoverOff").addClass("hover");
        }, 0);
        a.data("timer", b);
        a.on("mouseout", function() {
          var b = Number(a.data("timer"));
          null != b && clearTimeout(b);
          b = setTimeout(function() {
            a
              .off("mouseout")
              .removeClass("hover")
              .addClass("hoverOff");
          }, 500);
          a.data("timer", b);
        });
      }
    });
  });
})();
```